# Ethereum HD wallet collision?

Tags: truffle, metamask, hd-wallets

I created random HD wallet seed using `eth-hd-wallet` package, then imported it into Metamask and got expected addresses:

- 0xF011B485DF2A66A3019dEa82E1EBbf7C716443A1 (m/44'/60'/0'/0/0)
- 0x9590D9ca47290358eaF1Cc8482Beb2fc09D25c72 (m/44'/60'/0'/0/1)
- 0x3cAd996C8C9205374aECF81eE8EDd80f2489dA04 (m/44'/60'/0'/0/2)

... and so on. But when I am using the same mnenomic in `truffle-hdwallet-wallet` I see that zeroth address is `0x959fd7ef9089b7142b6b908dc3a8af7aa8ff0fa1`, second address `0x4e90a36b45879f5bae71b57ad525e817afa54890` that already has number of transactions on etherscan in Rinkeby testnet.

From now I have 2 questions:

1. How it could be, I mean duplication of mnemonic phrase?
2. Why `truffle-hdwallet-provider` shows me different address then Metanask or bitcore-generated ones?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it really was "duplicated" mnemonic phrase equal to... `undefined`.