# Keystore File vs Mnemonic Phrase 24 words (25 words)

Tags: wallets, security

I read [Ethereum HD wallet collision?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35130/ethereum-hd-wallet-collision) and I'm really scared. The user generates an already used private key and gets access to money from another man. IMHO it is scary. Or do I misunderstand something?

After reading that post I think what method the most secure: Keystore File, Mnemonic Phrase 24 words, Mnemonic Phrase 25 words.

My dilettante thoughts say to me that the most secure method is the last (Mnemonic Phrase 25 words).

But I have decided to ask the community because I'm a newbie in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As mentioned in the question you linked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/35131/39998), the mnemonic phrase was set to `undefined`. Another user was likely running into the same issue, causing the same mnemonic phrase to be used multiple times. This was not a collision in a randomly generated mnemonic phrase.

24 word long mnemonic phrases are generated from 256 bits of entropy, which is the same length as a standard Ethereum private key. You can use a passphrase to increase the entropy of the mnemonic phrase further.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood what you read.

Ethereum seed phrases are safe.